# How install and use different versions of pythons on MacOS using pyenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyenv

Starting out when I run `$ which python3` I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
```

And in my .zprofile I have:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

So starting out, I have 3.8 installed and it works. Now, I need to create a setup that will allow me to install and use different versions of python for different projects.

So, I tried the following:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install pyenv
$ pyenv version
```

It printed out `System`. So, it only sees the python 2.7 that comes with macos. Then I tried:

```
$ pyenv install 3.9.1
$ pyenv install 3.8.7
$ echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.zshrc
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

Now, at the end of my `.zshrc` file I have:

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

But I still just get `System` when I run `$ pyenv version`. I know the different python versions are getting installed in `~/.pyenv/versions` directory. So, what else am I supposed to do to get it
to list all the versions and switch back and forth between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, for `pyenv` to work correctly, you should uninstall the Python that's in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3` and remove it from your `$PATH`.

If you use `pyenv` to manage your Python versions, then you should not install Python in any other way. `pyenv` will update your path automatically as you switch Python version.

Next, you need to set `pyenv`‘s default Python version by doing

```
$ pyenv global 3.9.1
```

on the command line.

Finally, to switch Python versions, you can use

```
$ pyenv local 3.8.7
```

on the command line. Note, that setting the local Python is sticky and works on a per-directory basis. So, for each directory where you need a specific Python version, use this command once.

For more info, see https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md

Comment: Thank you so much! Removing the PATH from .zprofile allowed pyenv to start working properly. Unfortunately, it broke some stuff that was installed (poetry,  some projects installed using poetry, etc). But I am fixing those by reinstalling them.